# JQuery Scrollable Text Hide

Tags: html, jquery-plugins, scroll

I'm using [this](http://www.class.pm/files/jquery/uscrollbar/demo/#) plugin and I managed to get it working. But the thing is I want the body of text to be invisible until the user clicks a certain option. But for some reason it is visible all the time. Here's my html:

```
<div id="Hotel" class="Information" style="display:none">
<p>ljasdlaskdfjlkasjdflkajsdflkjaskldf</p>
<p>ljasdlaskdfjlkasjdflkajsdflkjaskldf</p>
<p>ljasdlaskdfjlkasjdflkajsdflkjaskldf</p>
<p>ljasdlaskdfjlkasjdflkajsdflkjaskldf</p>
<p>ljasdlaskdfjlkasjdflkajsdflkjaskldf</p>
<p>ljasdlaskdfjlkasjdflkajsdflkjaskldf</p>
<p>ljasdlaskdfjlkasjdflkajsdflkjaskldf</p>
<p>ljasdlaskdfjlkasjdflkajsdflkjaskldf</p>
</div>
```

Here's my JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.Information').uscrollbar();
    $("ul.navigation").click(function(e) {
        $sel = $(this).val();
        if($sel==1)
            $('#Hotel').show();
    });
});
```

Can anyone tell me why it is visible even though I set it to be invisible?

One more thing, how do I set the plugin's various options like autoHide? I tried this:

```
$('.Information').uscrollbar({
    autoHide: true,
});
```

But that didn't seem to work, any ideas? Thank you